# onClick event window.location.href instead of window.open issue in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good day, guys. I'm having trouble in this event. When I clicked the View Result it opens a new tab but I don't want to use that event instead I want to redirect to that page in the same tab instead of opening new tab. Thanks.

This is the code:

onclick='window.open(\"student_result.php?testid={$val["testid"]}\", \"_blank\")'>View Result

Comment: and why can't you use an `href` on an `<a>` to do it? Or change to `location.href="student_result.php.."`

Comment: use `location.href=url` instead of `window.open` or do what @charlietfl suggested above.

Comment: thanks guys I use this code and it works <a href='student_result.php?testid={$val["testid"]}'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the target. In your example `_blank` means "open in a new tab or window". Try `_self`:

```
onclick='window.open(\"student_result.php?testid={$val["testid"]}\", \"_self\")'>View Result
```

Here is a list of all target options:

> _self: Load the response into the same HTML4 frame (or HTML5 browsing context) as the current one. This value is the default if the
>   attribute is not specified.
>
> _blank: Load the response into a new unnamed HTML4 window or HTML5 browsing context.
>
> _parent: Load the response into the HTML4 frameset parent of the current frame or HTML5 parent browsing context of the current one. If
>   there is no parent, this option behaves the same way as _self.
>
> _top: In HTML4: Load the response into the full, original window, canceling all other frames. In HTML5: Load the response into the
>   top-level browsing context. If there is no
>   parent, this option behaves the same way as _self.
>
> From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Some browsers handle this differently, especially if you want to open new windows (aka. pop-ups). Please note: The other users are right. If you want to do it by best-practice, use a common link `<a>` instead. This way you can also use the above target options.